# How do I test if a variable represents a sequence?

Tags: sequence

I created a variable that represents a sequence:

```
mySeq = Sequence[1, 2, 3];
```

I wanted to use that variable as an argument for some functions. But I got in trouble. For example,

```
FreeQ[mySeq, 1]
```

generates an error message.

So I wanted to test if mySeq was a sequence before I used it as an argument. But there is no predicate SequenceQ and

```
Head[mySeq]
```

also generates an error message.

**Is there a way to test whether mySeq is a sequence object?**

Comment: It's possible that this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) (although it's an interesting question in it's own right). Can you instead define `mySeq` as a `List` and use `Apply`? For instance, if `mySeq = {1,2,3}`, then `f @@ mySeq` evaluates to `f[1, 2, 3]`. (`@@` is the infix form of `Apply`.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may make a helper function with attribute `SequenceHold`.

```
ClearAll[sequenceQ];
Attributes[sequenceQ] = {SequenceHold};
sequenceQ[_Sequence] = True;
sequenceQ[_] = False;
```

This can be used to test for a sequence directly or with mapping and threading functions as can the built in *`*Q`* functions.  Note that I use `Set` here instead of `SetDelayed` as it works better for this particular function definition.

```
mySeq = Sequence[1, 2, 3];
sequenceQ[mySeq]

(* True *)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Changed from `SetDelayed` to `Set` has it works better with this function.

Answer (score 7):

This tests if a symbol represents a `Sequence`:

```
With[{a = mySeq}, HoldComplete[a][[1, 0]]] === Sequence
```

or:

```
(mySeq -> 0)[[1, 0]] === Sequence
```

Comment: Great! But could you explain why HoldComplete[mySeq] and HoldComplete[a] in your solution have different results? The With[] scoping made the difference, but why?

Comment: @FernandoSaldanha Nothing happens inside HoldComplete. Hence it is needed for `mySeq` to be evaluated once before it is put into HoldComplete. Otherwise the result would be `HoldComplete[myseq]`. The first place where `mySeq` is evaluated must have attribute `SequenceHold` like `Set` which I've used. The trick can be done with `Rule` that also has `SequenceHold`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But why do you need the call to Set to be within the first argument of With[] ? Without this the assignment to a would not help.

Answer (score 7):

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{FreeQ},
 SetAttributes[FreeQ, SequenceHold];
 FreeQ[mySeq, 1]
]
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Answer (score 6):

How about this, which doesn't require any tests:

```
mySeq = Sequence[1, 2, 3];
seqFreeQ[s__, x_] := FreeQ[Flatten[{s}], x]
seqFreeQ[mySeq, 1]
(* ==> False *)
```

The first argument of the function allows a sequence, which is then wrapped in a `List` to apply `FreeQ`. The `Flatten` is optional.